# How to play song in loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer

While using AvAudio Player How can we achieve a song to be played in a loop? 
I want that after finishing one song how can we repeat the song again??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AVAudioPlayerDelegate and implement:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

You can do something like this:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [player play];
}
```

Or you can allow it to stop based on some condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[yourSound numberOfLoops: -1];
```

-1 indicates the sound is being looped forever.